# Firefox width issue

Tags: css, width, image-resizing, styled-components

I recently made my Web Developer portfolio: http://rafaelmuttoni.com/ and everything seemed fine.

Until a random guy opened a issue in my repo about a sizing problem happening in Firefox.

I just cannot figure out why this happens ONLY in Firefox.

When I hover the navbar the list items just go huge.

You can inspect or go to this link, which is the styled file of the navbar: https://github.com/rafaelmuttoni/rafaelmuttoni.com/blob/master/src/components/Navbar/styled.js

[You can check the issue in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYYZ8.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem begins because of the **svg** tag. They don't have their own fixed size and depends on the size of parent element. Somehow in Firefox they are reacting on parent width scaling.

I just try to set fix widht in css of the svg icons and it helped.

```
.dQgIel {
width: 32px;
}
```

Just add it to your existing css

```
.dQgIel {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 32px; /*the cure*/
}
```